# singular chain complex modulo subdivision

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $S_p(X)$ be the p-th singular chain group and $\mathcal S(X)$ be the singular chain complex of a topological space $X$. There is a barycentric subdivision operator (which is also a chain map) $sd: S_p(X) \to S_p(X)$ as is defined in standard topology textbooks such as Munkres. There is a chain homotopy from $sd$ to $id_{\mathcal S(X)}$.

Let $D_p$ be the subgroup of $S_p(X)$ generated by $T - sd(T)$ such that $T \in S_p(X)$. Then $\mathcal D:= (D_p)$ is a chain subcomplex of $\mathcal S(X)$. **I wonder whether the homology of the quotient chain complex $\mathcal S(X)/\mathcal D$ is isomorphic to the homology of $\mathcal S(X)$.**

I think it is a quite natural question. There is an equivalence relation $\sim$ in $S_p(X)$ generated by $(T, sd(T))$, and $\mathcal S(X)/\mathcal D$ is simply $\mathcal S(X)$ modulo $\sim$.

By zig-zag lemma, the homology of $\mathcal S(X)/\mathcal D$ and $\mathcal S(X)$ are isomorphic if and only if $\mathcal D$ is acyclic. **I don't know how to prove or disprove $\mathcal D$ is acyclic.**

It has been answered in MO ([link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/410230/homology-of-singular-chain-complex-modulo-subdivision)).

Answer (score 0):

You aim to show that if $H_n(D)=0$ for each $n$. Then $H_n(X,D)\cong H_n(X)$ for each $n$.

Consider the short exact sequence of the following chain complexes:

$0\rightarrow S_{*}(D)\rightarrow S_{*}(X)\rightarrow \frac{S_{*}(X)}{S_{*}(D)}\rightarrow 0$

This induces a long exact sequence in homology:

$...\rightarrow H_n(D)\rightarrow H_n(X)\rightarrow H_n(X,D)\rightarrow H_{n-1}(D)\rightarrow...$

Since $H_n(D)=H_{n-1}(D)=0$, we get a short exact sequence:

$0\rightarrow H_n(X)\rightarrow H_n(X,D)\rightarrow 0$ for each $n$.

This implies that $H_n(X)\cong H_n(X,D)$.  $\square$

Comment: Thank you. But what I actually mean is that I don't know how to prove or disprove $\mathcal D$ is acyclic. My description of the question is not very clear, sorry if that misled you. I will edit the expression soon.